# How to execute statements like "service jboss start" or "./jboss.sh start" within a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I need to create a shell script where I need to execute commands like "service jboss start" or "./jboss.sh start" within the script itself.

Comment: For most shells you put each command you want to execute on a line by itself as if you were doing the commands in a console. I can't give you an answer unless you state which shell you're using.

Comment: I am using bash. When I am using #! /usr/bin/expect -- I am not able to execute the command. 
However while using #!/bin/bash I can execute the same.

Comment: And why do you use `#!/usr/bin/expect`? What is it?

Comment: @stek29 in unix if its the first line of a shell script it will tell unix to use that shell/interpreter to run the script in. @user5280709 Although if your using bash you should put `#!/usr/bin/bash`. That is probably your problem. Look at stek's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create file which starts with [sha-bang](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html), it tells system *which program* are needed to run this. In your case you should **put** `#!/bin/sh` (or `#!/bin/bash` if `sh` isn't link to `bash`) **at first line**.
You also need to make it executable, it can be done with `chmod +x script.sh`.
So here is it:
*script.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
service jboss start
./jboss.sh start
```

And after creating file run this:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

And for execution:

```
./script.sh
```